# What aspects of a GPO is stored in AD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I'd like to know what components of a GPO are stored in Active Directory.  Is it all on the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing *in* the GPO is stored in the AD database, really. It's all in the SYSVOL (IIRC) on the domain controllers. AD has a GUID pointer to the location on the filesystem, and of course who it applies to, any permissions on it, etc.

Comment: The GPC is stored in AD and the GPT is stored in SYSVOL, which I think is what you're saying, but one without the other would be of no use.

Comment: Yup, you got the terminology correct.

Comment: You got what I was looking for... where is the GUID pointer within AD?

Comment: CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=something,DC=something,DC=something

Comment: @Maker - you can find that sort of thing by doing a little bit of google-searching, a little bit of studying/certification for AD, or by just playing around with tools like AD Explorer from SysInternals. I'm not telling you not to ask questions here, and your main question was a good one - but once you got the details on the GPC and GPT from @joeqwerty, you definitely should have had enough info to go find the easy things on your own.